# Postman test - automation test

Tags: json, postman

How can I write a *Postman* test that checks if my response body contains `nets": {"4": "1"}`?
I have trouble to put this `"parameter_list": { "2": ...` part into `pm.expect()`. "parmeter_list" can contain many objects with name that is "number"

```
{
    "request_id": 358624578,
    "product_list": [
        {
            "symbol": "AX-174",
            "value_ids": [
                271,
                1437038,
                .
                .
                .
                1757620
            ],
            "id": 65869
        }
    ],
    "do_show": true,
    "do_show_list": {
        "do_show_products": true,
        "do_show_parameters": true,
        "do_show_parameter_values": true,
        "do_show_flags": false
    },
    "parameter_list": {
        "2": {
            "value_type_id": 0,
            "name_full_txt": "Producent",
            "unit_text": null,
            "product_count": 1,
            "nets": {
                "3": "1"
            },
            "pos": 0,
            "id": 2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to write a test only for "2" key in the parameter_list?

Comment: Also, could you update your question Headline? 'Postman test - automation test' is not quite informative.

Comment: No, sorry. I want  check for every occurrence in possible object in "parameter_list"

Comment: Updated my answer with the scenario for multiple objects in parameter_list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to test only against "2" key in *parameter_list*, I would suggest the following solution:

```
const jsonBody = pm.response.json();
const parameterList = jsonBody.parameter_list["2"];
const nets = {
    "nets": {
        "4": "1"
    }
};

pm.test("check parameter '2' contains nets",  () => pm.expect(parameterList).to.deep.include(nets));
```

I believe, that you can easily modify both `nets` and `parameterList` to match your actual case.

**EDIT:**
If you need to iterate over all objects in *parameter_list* you can use `for..in` loop within your test:

```
const jsonBody = pm.response.json();
const nets = {
    "nets": {
        "3": "1"
    }
};

pm.test("check all parameters contains nets",  () => {
    for(let parameter in jsonBody.parameter_list) {
        pm.expect(jsonBody.parameter_list[parameter]).to.deep.include(nets);
    }
});
```

Or for more readability use `tests[]`:

```
for(let parameter in jsonBody.parameter_list) {
    tests[`Check 'nets' object is in ${parameter} parameter`] = pm.expect(jsonBody.parameter_list[parameter]).to.deep.include(nets);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @n-verbitsky accepted answer, Postman provides test snippets in the 'test' tab of a request. More information on testing in Postman and how to write test scripts can be taken from their docs: [learning center](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/test-examples/).

I think it would be beneficial to show the test code you already have written.

[image]